# How to prevent known and unknown bots c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bots

I have a simple web application, which is hosted and I have enable google search so google bots crawls, i cant find many unknown bots crawls in my application. I need to know the valid users visiting the website(except bots).

I have used

```
httprequest.Browser.Crawler
```

But it doesn’t works properly.

Can anyone please help me to prevent this fully?

Comment: This is properly because most crawlers are identified by their useragent. not all bots comply to using a crawler specific useragent - you can find some here http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/ and then look at the request for the useragent string

Comment: I'd say you would be better off making sure you can handle bots, than trying to limit them.

Comment: It's impossible to prevent it fully as bots can perfectly impersonate a regular user, and you'd have no way to detect it. Check user agent and crawler, and that's as good as you're going to get

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Request.UserAgent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see the UserAgent og requests, and then match that to a list of [Crawler UserAgent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/)

I would properly use a filter for this and then apply it in your filterconfig

```
public class CrawlerFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var userAgent = context.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
        //Do something with the userAgent and/or drop the request
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that not all crawler abide by this, so you can't really be "super" certain.

## Edit

i just learned that `Request.Browser.Crawler` is basically what I've suggested above, although the list (from Browser.Crawler) seems to not be maintained very well.

Comment: whether [list of crawler useragent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/) are up to date? and some of the users use google proxies so how can i distinguish them?

Comment: Not by UserAgent, but the hostname they come from is something like  google-proxy-[IPAddress].google.com